# How do I get the classes of all columns in a data frame?

Tags: r

What is an easy way to find out what class each column is in a data frame?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

One option is to use `lapply` and `class`. For example:

```
> foo <- data.frame(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2))
> names(foo) <- c("SomeFactor", "SomeNumeric")
> lapply(foo, class)
$SomeFactor
[1] "factor"

$SomeNumeric
[1] "numeric"
```

Another option is `str`:

```
> str(foo)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SomeFactor : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
 $ SomeNumeric: num  1 2
```

Comment: Since `class` returns a character vector of _all_ classes an object inherits from, the output of `sapply(foo, class)` might be a list, and not always a character vector as most people would expect. Which can be a bit dangerous... I find `lapply` a lot safer.

Comment: for better readability I suggest: ```unlist(lapply(foo, class))``` which is handy with data frames with a lot of columns.

Comment: `unlist` with `lapply` is a terrible idea because it is possible that `length(class(x))>1`  (see comments above) -- `sapply` is a lot safer than `unlist + lapply`. a safe way would be `sapply(lapply(foo, class), "[", 1)` - given that foo is a data frame

Comment: One could also use `do.call(c, lapply(foo, class))` to obtain a vector of classes.

Answer (score 33):

You can simple make use of `lapply` or `sapply` builtin functions.

`lapply` will return you a `list` -

```
lapply(dataframe,class)
```

while `sapply` will take the best possible return type ex. Vector etc -

```
sapply(dataframe,class)
```

Both the commands will return you all the column names with their respective class.

Answer (score 3):

Hello was looking for the same, and it could be also

```
unlist(lapply(mtcars,class))
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a more compact output than the great answers above using `lapply`, so here's an alternative wrapped as a small function.

```r
# Example data
df <-
    data.frame(
        w = seq.int(10),
        x = LETTERS[seq.int(10)],
        y = factor(letters[seq.int(10)]),
        z = seq(
            as.POSIXct('2020-01-01'),
            as.POSIXct('2020-10-01'),
            length.out = 10
        )
    )

# Function returning compact column classes
col_classes <- function(df) {
    t(as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) paste(class(x), collapse = ','))))
}

# Return example data's column classes
col_classes(df)
```

```
  [,1]            
w "integer"       
x "character"     
y "factor"        
z "POSIXct,POSIXt"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want your result to be a 1-column matrix? Why? How about a character vector instead?

Comment: Sure, why not return a 1-column matrix? I stated this solution is for a compact output, useful for returning to check after manipulating a data.frame for example. It isn't meant to be used for downstream processing of column classes. The other answers above return a character vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr` as well, which is similar to `apply` family functions:

```
as.data.frame(purrr::map_chr(mtcars, class))
purrr::map_df(mtcars, class)
```