# Ordered factors cause sapply(df, class) to return list instead of vector

Tags: r, dataframe, types

Other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661159/how-do-i-get-the-classes-of-all-columns-in-a-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125222/determine-the-data-types-of-an-r-data-frames-columns)) have recommended the use of `sapply(df, class)` to get a vector of column classes (analogous to `pandas.DataFrame.dtypes`).

An example of how this works correctly:

```
# make some example data
n          <- 10
categories <- c('jacket','t-shirt','leg warmers')
colors     <- c('teal','neon yellow','hot pink')
sizes      <- c('XS','S','M','L','XL')
items      <- data.frame(item_id       = 1:n,
                         item_category = sample(categories, n, r=TRUE),
                         item_color    = sample(colors, n, r=TRUE),
                         item_size     = sample(sizes, n, r=TRUE))

sapply(items, class) # returns character vector of length 4
#   item_id item_category    item_color     item_size 
# "integer"      "factor"      "factor"      "factor"
```

However, if at least one column is an ordered factor, `sapply(df, class)` returns a list.

```
items2 <- items
items2$item_size <- factor(items2$item_size, levels=sizes, ordered=TRUE)

sapply(items2, class) # returns list of 4
# $item_id
# [1] "integer"
# 
# $item_category
# [1] "factor"
# 
# $item_color
# [1] "factor"
# 
# $item_size
# [1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Note that `sapply(items2, typeof)` still returns a vector, albeit of column **types** ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855589/1217536) of why this is different) which returns "integer", the storage mode for the factor class.

I need a vector of classes for a pre-processing routine, and I'm really only interested in the *main class* ("factor" not "ordered").  What is the best way to do this?

My self-answered solution may not be the most robust, so I welcome alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?class`, the function returns "a vector of classes an object inherits from."

Assuming that they are returned in the order where first inherits from second inherits from third, etc, the main class would be last in the sequence:

```
sapply(items2, function(x) tail(class(x),1) )
#   item_id item_category    item_color     item_size 
# "integer"      "factor"      "factor"      "factor"
```

Comment: You could replace `rev(class(x))[1]` with `tail(class(x), 1)`.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 actually, on larger vectors yours would be more efficient. It's easier to select the last element than to reverse an entire vector first and then select the first element. Fastest would be: `{cl <- class(x) ; cl[length(cl)]}`.

Comment: @JorisMeys agreed, but my original answer was the `rev()`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 oops, my mistake :-)