# Generate a list of factor columns

Tags: r, class, types

I know that I can use `sapply` to find out the class of data columns like this:

```
sapply(data, class)
```

Code above similar to: [How do I get the classes of all columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661159/how-do-i-get-the-classes-of-all-columns-in-a-data-frame)

However, how would determine and store a vector of column names, `fac` that are of class `factor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fac <- names(data)[sapply(data, is.factor)]`

Comment: This gives you a vector, but you mentioned you want a list. You can also try `as.list(names(data)[sapply(data, is.factor)])` unless vector is what you really wanted :)

Comment: @AntoniosK thank you for the catch, I meant `vector`. Corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way would be to use `purrr` package:

```
names(iris)[purrr::map_lgl(iris, is.factor)]
#"Species"

which(map_lgl(iris, is.factor) == TRUE) #this will return the column index as well.
#Species 
#5
```